# How to Instantiate an entire XAML Grid object in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, object, grid

I'd like to instantiate an entire XAML Grid object in C#.  My Grid object is a beast, it has 9 user-input fields, borders, labels and images.

I also want five instances of my Grid object, and I would like to instantiate them during run-time on the fly (with a press of a button). Is this possible?  What is the best approach?  Here is my Grid object...

```
 <Grid Margin="2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Background="#505050" ></Label>
                        </Border>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Text="TRANSFORM" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Text="Position" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="x " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="y " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="z " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="transform_x" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2" ></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="transform_y" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2" ></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="transform_z" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2" ></TextBox>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Text="Rotation"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="x " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="y " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="z " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="rotation_x" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="rotation_y" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="rotation_z" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBox>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Text="Scale" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="x " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="y " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="z " VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Foreground="#FD3777" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="scale_x" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="scale_y" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name ="scale_z" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="10" Background="#707070" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="./resources/#Pilsen" Margin="2"></TextBox>

                    </Grid>
```

Comment: The text and labels, etc. are all fixed? Do you access the controls at all?

Comment: Yes text and labels are all fixed, I would only want to access the TextBox elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply new up a Grid in code

```
Grid grid = new Grid() { Margin = new Thickness(2) };
```

and add elements to it eg.

```
grid.Children.Add(new Border());
TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
t.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
t.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
grid.Children.Add(t);
//etc...
```

Or you could add a UserControl item to your project and put your Grid inside its xaml. Then you can new up as many MyGridControl's as you want.

Comment: But I have it already done in XAML, is there a way to simply instantiate a new one from C#?

Comment: Yes, encapsulate your Grid in a UserControl as mentioned. Add -> New item... User Control (WPF). Replace the empty Grid in XAML with your Grid. Rebuild..., your control will appear in the toolbox. Now you can either drag it onto the MainWindow or new one up from code and add it to the Children of a named Panel element.

Comment: Ok thanks! This will help a lot.  I'm going to go the UserControl approach

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- create a `UserControl` containing your grid, say `MyBeastGrid`
- in your destination form have a placeholder where those instantiated grids should be placed, say `MyPlaceholder`
- add a button (or other triggering mechanism that should add the `MyBeastGrid` to `MyPlaceholder`)
- in the button's `Click` event handler you simply call `MyPlaceholder.Children.Add(new MyBeastGrid());`

If you need to pass some parameters to `MyBeastGrid`, define some public properties there and either provide parameterised constructor or call your grid with `new MyBeastGrid() { Property1 = value1, Property2 = value2 };`

I suggest you use `ScrollViewer` to store your `MyBeastGrid` instances as it provides scrolling out of the box.

Comment: Thanks very much Mike, you make the most sense!  I had one question regarding the MyPlaceholder part - how does that look like in XAML?

Comment: If you like the answer, don't forget to +1 it and accept is. The "MyPlaceholder" is a Panel item (e.g. a StackPanel) named "MyPlaceholder".  The XAML would simply be `<StackPanel x:Name="MyPlaceholder" Orientation="Horizontal" />`

Comment: Ok great, just needed some clarification on that, and yes did the +1 now :)